# How to use GnuPG to sign with private key having an empty passphrase?

Tags: rsa, gnupg, openpgp

I used GnuPG to  create an RSA key pair xxx@xxx.com. When I created it, I set an empty passphrase.

```
$ gpg --gen-key
```

When generating the key pair, it prompts: "You need a passphrase to...", where I pressed enter twice, and it can success list public key and secret key:

```
 $ gpg --gpg --list-keys
```

Now I want to sign yyy@yyy.com with xxx@xxx.com's private key.

I have tried to only press enter, but it did not work and raises an error instead:

> Invalid passphrase: please try again
>
> Please enter the passphrase to unlock the secret key.

How to bypass the error?

Comment: `null` is usually considered something undefined, which the empty string is not. For me, creating such a key worked fine. What operating system are you using, what terminal?

Comment: debian 7,  putty remote login

Comment: I fear you're passing a `\r\n` to GnuPG, which this reads as the passphrase being `\r`.But I'm sorry, I can't tell you how to remove this. For testing, use some command line editor to save a new line to a file and look for `\r` characters (the `file` utility might help here, or `hexdump`).